# Return subset of properties from a node through Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin

Is there a way to return just a subset of all properties of a graph node with a Gremlin query?

I know you cand use the transform pipe to concatenate property values, but I'm more interested in obtaining structured results  (like propertyName1 = value1, propertyName2 = value2).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using Table??

Sample from : [Gremlin Wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Pattern-Match-Pattern)

```
gremlin> t = new Table()                                                       
gremlin> g.v(1).out('knows').as('x').out('created').as('y').table(t){it.name}{it.name}
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
gremlin> t
==>[x:josh, y:ripple]
==>[x:josh, y:lop]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Gremlin-Groovy, I find using Groovy's each construct to be a useful way to create my own objects from Gremlin query results.  For example:

```
nodes = []
g.V.each{ node ->
  nodes += [ propertyName1 : node.value1, propertyName2 : node.value2 ]
}
```

Now you have a List of Map objects representing nodes returned from your query. It's possible this isn't the most efficient way but it is very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

As of Gremlin 2.4.0, you can do:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).out.map('name')
==>{name=vadas}
==>{name=josh}
==>{name=lop}
gremlin> g.v(1).out.map('name','age')
==>{age=27, name=vadas}
==>{age=32, name=josh}
==>{age=null, name=lop}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible doing [this](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#transform-1):

If data is:

```
gremlin> g.E.has('weight', T.gt, 0.5f).outV.age
==>32
==>29
```

Then the query to do is:

```
gremlin> g.E.has('weight', T.gt, 0.5f).outV.transform{[id:it.id,age:it.age]}
==>{id=4, age=32}
==>{id=1, age=29}
```